# Converting server to allow Apache write access to certain directories, does this solution look right?

Tags: debian, permissions, systemd, apache-httpd, umask

I've been at this all day and think I finally figured it out, but want to make sure before I put it into production.

I'm changing my server to allow the `apache:apache` user write permission on a few directories. I'm the only user `jeff:jeff` on the server.

My directory structure looks something like this:

```
/home/jeff/www/                       0755 jeff:jeff
/home/jeff/www/example1.com/          0755 jeff:jeff
/home/jeff/www/example2.com/          0755 jeff:jeff
/home/jeff/www/example2.com/uploads/  0755 apache:apache
```

**The problem is:**

I run `chmod apache:apache uploads/` to allow `apache` write access.

Whenever I want to edit a file in `uploads/` via sftp, I have to `chown` it back to `jeff:jeff`, then reverse when I'm done.

**My preliminary solution is:**

- Add `apache` user to `jeff` group
- Give `jeff` group write permission on `uploads/` dir via manual `chmod 775`
- Force `apache` user to create any new files + folders + subfolders as `apache:jeff`. Requires `setgid 2775` on `uploads/` dir
- Force `apache` user to create any new files + folders + subfolders with `umask 002` = `775` via [systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31154944/142233)

I'm only about 50% sure I've got all this right.

Does it sound okay? Is there a better way? Did I miss anything?

**With Jim's help, here is the final solution I used:**

For my reference.

```
# usermod --append --groups apache jeff

> Relogin all sessions

# chown -R apache:apache www/example.com/uploads/
# find www/example.com/uploads/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
# find www/example.com/uploads/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;

# systemctl edit --full php.service

-----------
[Service]
UMask=0002
-----------

# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl restart php
```

WordPress users will want to add this to their wp-config.php:

```
define('FS_CHMOD_DIR', 0775);
define('FS_CHMOD_FILE', 0664);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the general idea, and you're fairly close, but I would suggest that rather than adding the `apache` user to the `jeff` group, it would be slightly more secure and perhaps a tad more convenient (and extensible, if that's important) to do it the other way 'round:

0. Take `apache` out of the `jeff` group.
1. Instead, add `jeff` to the `apache` group.  For starters, this prevents `apache` from having read access to all the `jeff` group files.
2. `chown` the `uploads/` directory to be `apache:apache` and `chmod 775` so that anyone in the `apache` group can create/delete files there.
3. Have `apache` create files using `umask 2` so that anything `apache` creates is group-writeable.

This way:

A) You no longer have to `chown` files before you can edit them; all the `upload` files are owned by group `apache`, are group-writable, and you already belong to the `apache` group.

B) You have the ability to easily add other users to the `apache` group and they, too, will be able to edit uploaded files.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try tomorrow morning. What about the `setgid 2775` part? Is that still required? My understanding is this forces any files/folders under the 2775 directory to have the same group as the parent dir.

Comment: @Jeff If you can remember/script to `umask 2` before doing any work in this directory, then that's enough.  If you don't want to remember to do that each time, then `setgid 2775` is a robust alternative.

Comment: I see now that using Jim's answer, I no longer need to worry about `setgid` because the group stays `apache`.

Comment: Adding users to apache group would mean that david also can access jeff's apache files